# Retryrequest() of httpClient method not invoked during Rest API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, httpclient

The Rest API responds with 429 error code and the retry has to trigger 3 times .But the control isn't reaching the retryrequestethod of HttpRequestretryHandler class. Any specific reason for this ? Pseudo code below:-

```
@Override protected CloseableHttpClient newClient() {
 return HttpClients.custom()
   .disableAutomaticRetries().setServiceUnavailabilityRetryStrategy(retryCount,retryIntervalinMillis).setConnectionManager().setKeepAliveStrategy()
   .build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate resttemplate(){
   return new ResttemplateBuilder().requestFactory(this::clientHttpRequestFactory).build();
}

    private static Class HttpServiceUnavailabilityStrategy implements ServiceUnavailabilityStrategy{
@Override
public boolean retryrequest(HttpResponse resp,int executionCount,HttpContext){
return executionCount < = maxRetryCount && resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value();

    }
```

Comment: please show some code & where does issue comes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AshishPatil sure will do that

Answer (score 0):

`setServiceUnavailabilityRetryStrategy` needs `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` instance. I am not seeing you have set it correctly. You might need to do following inside `newClient` :

```
return HttpClients.custom()
   .disableAutomaticRetries().setServiceUnavailabilityRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {                 
                    @Override
                    public boolean retryRequest(HttpResponse response, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
                        return executionCount < = maxRetryCount && resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value();;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public long getRetryInterval() {
                        return 0; //you can set intervanl based on your need
                    }                   
                }).setConnectionManager().setKeepAliveStrategy()
   .build();
```

Moreover, by this way, you don't really need to define `HttpServiceUnavailabilityStrategy`  class.

Comment: Sorry , it was my typo error , i already have the above code in mine . Still it doesnt work.

Comment: return HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .disableAutomaticRetries()
    .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(
      new HttpServiceUnavailabilityStrategy(retryCount, retryIntervalMillis))
    .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager()).setKeepAliveStrategy(connectionKeepAliveStrategy())
    .build();

Comment: You have it, but method signature was wrong, please recheck my implementation & give it a try.